# Tremolo Bar for Fender USA Stratocaster

Tags: electric-guitar, tremolo-system

It appears there are different size tremolo bars for Fender Stratocasters. I want to make sure I order the right one. Mine's made in the USA. Any info appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this something you could contact Fender customer service with? I'm sure that if you provide them with your guitar's serial number they will be super happy to advice which one is the best for you.

Answer (score 2):

Visit the Fender website and you'll see a large selection of tremolo bars for different guitars and years. Remember to buy the small spring as well (keeps the arm in the place you want it to stay). These are often lost, or people don't know what they are.